# How to read multiple XLSX files form a particular folder and write them one by one to a single xlsx file

Tags: c#, .net, parsing, xlsx

I am working on a console application where a path for a folder is given and have to select all the xlsx files form that folder and store it in a list. Then write them one by one to a new xlsx file.. I did try certain code but is not working..

This is my code. Any help will be appreciated.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
            int rCnt;
            int cCnt;
            int rc = 0;
            int cc = 0;
            string s;

            DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(@"D:\T01052\Programs\C#\Programs\Excel into Excel\Excel into Excel\Excel into Excel\Excel file\Input File");

            FileInfo[] Files = d.GetFiles("*.xlsx");

            List<string> lstr = new List<string>();

            int filecount = 0;

            foreach (FileInfo file in Files)
            {
                Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
                Excel.Workbook wb = null;
                Excel.Worksheet ws = null;

                s = file.Directory + "\\" + file.Name;
                lstr.Add(s);

                wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(lstr[filecount]);
                ws = (Excel.Worksheet)wb.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
                Excel.Range range;
                range = ws.UsedRange;

                rCnt = range.Rows.Count;
                cCnt = range.Columns.Count;

                for (rCnt = 1; rCnt <= rc; rCnt++)
                {
                    for (cCnt = 1; cCnt <= cc; cCnt++)
                    {
                        s = (string)(range.Cells[rCnt, cCnt] as Excel.Range).Value2;
                    }
                }

                wb.SaveAs(@"D:\T01052\Programs\C#\Programs\Excel into Excel\Excel into Excel\Excel into Excel\Excel file\Outpoot File\Output.xlsx");

                wb.Close(true, null, null);
                xlApp.Quit();

                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlApp);
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(wb);
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(ws);

                filecount = filecount + 1;
                foreach (Process clsProcess in Process.GetProcesses())
                {
                    if (clsProcess.ProcessName.Equals("EXCEL"))
                    {
                        clsProcess.Kill();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: excel xls is not xml.  Change tag.

Comment: If you have to do `clsProcess.Kill()` then you're doing something wrong.

Comment: I am doing that because in case of reading multiple files, after the first file is completed the code throws an error as the Excel.exe process is still running and as a reason it was not going to the next xlsx file..

Comment: Do you have any alternative way of doing that..?

Comment: @HarishShah - You need to write your code so that Excel closes cleanly. If you are killing processes then your code is wrong.

Comment: @HarishShah - You may need to call `Marshal.ReleaseComObject` on every single Excel object you reference. That includes each `.Cell(,)` each `range.Rows`, `range.Columns`, etc.